# Comparing 2 servers (Xeon vs Opteron)

Tags: xeon, opteron

I currently rent a server:

```
Intel® Xeon® X3440 Quadcore 4x 2.1 GHz, 16 GB DDR3 ECC
```

Now I have a possibility to get the following server for a cheaper price:

```
AMD Opteron™ 3280 Octo-Core 8x 2.4 GHz, 24 GB DIMM (DDR3) ECC
```

Do you reccomend me to move to a new server? I don't know a lot about differences beween Xeon and Opetron. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly do you NEED extra performance, as moving from one to the other will be time consuming, risky to some degree and incur an outage.

That Xeon has hyperthreading, so you can kind of think of it as being able to do eight things at once, same as the Opteron. Normally I'd always take an Intel over an AMD as on anything but price Intel almost always rules the roost but there's at least one generational leap between the 2009 Xeon and the much modern Opteron - and that does cancel out the 'Intel lead' I'd normally go with.

One thing's for sure, unless you're memory-starved or use code that hates hyperthreading then there's not *that* much in it between them, though if this were a new system I'd probably go with the Opteron (or nag the Xeon supplier for a more modern chip).

But it really does all come down to whether the ~0%-20% overall likely performance difference is worth the move.

Comment: Do not forget the opteron is cheaper as the poster said. Though if you rent that long, BUYING may be a better optin. Get a Dell with a 3 year warrantey on a lease and save money.